# Can this foreach be improved?

Tags: c#, foreach

This `foreach` is intended to look through a list and when a match is found it returns the *next* element. Can it be improved?

```
public static string GetCommandLineArg(string arg)
{
    var doreturn = false;

    foreach (var item in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
        if (doreturn)
            return item;
        else if (arg == item)
            doreturn = true;

    return null;
}
```

The part I am concerned with is the returning of the next item.

The inner `if` statement is messy and the use of an extra variable seems unnecessary. Is there a simple function call or property which can be used with a `foreach` to return the next item?

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pFc4dU

Comment: Will this ever get the last item?

Comment: well, you could use `{` brackets to define a block scope around the for and elses. There are some problems mentioned by the other commenters. Why not look add the [CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine/) nuget package?

Comment: So just trying to debug this a bit. It seems like you are returning the  next arguement after the one you passed. Is this what you want?

Comment: A for loop maybe? You can simply use the index+1 and check for last index to return.

Comment: I feel the point of this routine has been missed. I state in the first line of the post "when a match is found it returns the next element". The next element - the one after the match.

Comment: What is a better approach for you? Less lines of code? Less memory-consuming? Faster? Your question is unclear and thus you get many answers that may or may not fit your needs. How would you chose the best answer on such an opinion-based question? If you provide what "better" means, you may ask this question at codereview.stackexhange.com

Comment: Edited to provide clarity of the problem. A for loop could be used, but foreach seems cleaner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Approach with Linq

```
public static string GetCommandLineArg(string arg)
{
    return Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().SkipWhile(x => x != arg).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zsIhtv

Comment: Awesome :) https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAZ295

Comment: @MattW you're welcome. If you want the `-` character instead of `null` you could also define a default value `.SkipWhile(x => x != arg).Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty("-").First();`

Comment: @eocron This is actually find and solves the problem in a concise, neat manner. It's all too easy to forget about completely different code structures when trying to refine a particular one.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a forech loop? would it be simpler with for loop?

```
var items = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];
        if (arg == item && i < items.Count())
            return items[i+1];
    }
```

Comment: How is this simpler than a foreach? It´s just a different approach, but **better**?

Comment: I am not sure if this is "neater/cleaner/more efficient" it fails on every score

Comment: In a way it removes the doreturn flag and saves 1 extra loop compared to `foreach`.

Comment: The original code sample gets stuck (once 'doreturn' is set to true it never resets), so in this respect this is simpler as you do not have to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always search for right key, I think you should just parse entire arguments into key-value collection, and then just retrieve them by key:

```
public Dictionary<string, dynamic> Parse(string[] args)
{
   //magic here
}

var argIndex = Parse(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());

var host = (string)argIndex["--server-host"];
var userName = (string)argIndex["--user"];
var ageOfEmpires = (int)argIndex["-age"];
```

This probably will be fastest approach.
As mentioned by @Icepickle, you could use [CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.CommandLine/) nuget package for Parse implementation, or write it yourself based on syntax of your arguments.